# Can ASP.NET outputCacheProfiles be used with Response.Cache?

Tags: .net, asp.net, caching, outputcache

When using the @OutputCache directive, you can define cache profiles as follows in web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <caching>
    <outputCacheSettings>
      <outputCacheProfiles>
        <add name="myprofile" duration="30" enabled="true" varyByParam="myfield"/>
      </outputCacheProfiles>
    </outputCacheSettings>
  </caching>
</system.web>
```

However, in my app, I have some pages that need to use programmatic caching instead of declarative e.g.:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
```

Is it possible to use Response.Cache and leverage the outputCacheProfiles?
For example,

```
Response.Cache.ApplyCacheProfile("myprofile");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the cacheability property is called location so you don't need to set that programatically, as for the other why not just try it and see?

Comment: My call to ApplyCacheProfile() was just pseudo code. The method does not exist. I am asking if such a method exists.

Answer (score 0):

At MVC you can use attributes over controllers `[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "myprofile")]`